# Class load issue JUnit 4.11

Tags: java, junit

I am trying JUnit 4.11. I wrote this sample provided at JUnit FooTest.java

```
public class FooTest{

  @Test
  public void thisAlwaysPass(){
  }

}
```

I have the JUnit 4.11 jar and the Hamcrest jar at `/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/ext`

Now when I run the following command, it says that it is unable to find the class.

```
$ java -cp . org.junit.runner.JUnitCore FooTest
JUnit version 4.11

could not find class : FooTest

Time : 0.002

OK (0 Tests)
```

I thought there is some problem with the classpath. So I tried without JUnit, and it said that main is missing:

```
$ java -cp . FooTest
Error: main method not found in FooTest
```

So Java is able to load the class. But when I try to run with JUnit, it cannot find the class. I have a basic understanding of the java class loading. Am I missing something here with JUnit?

I am using Fedora 17 & OpenJDK 1.7

Comment: Just guessing, but shouldn't you provide the fully qualified class name of `FooTest`?

Comment: But I have not put that inside a package. Is that mandatory?

Comment: Removing junit would not help.. cause you need main()

Comment: @rozar Yes I know I just wanted to find whether java can load the class. And it loads.

Comment: Really though, this would be much easier if you were using maven or gradle, which have figured out all the classpath issues for you.

Comment: I feel the problem is not with the classpath. Because the java is able to load and complain main is missing. It is JUnit which is not loading the class.

Answer (score 0):

What I guess is that. FooTest is not in the classpath. 
Try this

```
java -cp pathtojunit\junit-4.11.jar;pathtohamcrest\hamcrest.jar;pathto\FooTest.class; 
orj.junit.runner.JUnitCore FooTest
```

Or You can put all your jars and your test class in one folder say c:\junittest\ and try this

```
javac -cp c:\junittest\*; FooTest.java
java -cp c:\junittest\*; org.junit.runner.JUnitCore FooTest
```

Comment: No its is available in the current folder. I am passing the "." to -cp

Comment: So you have all the junit and FooTest and hamcrest in one folder and you are running your command from that folder? Because what cp does is it overrides the javaclass path

Comment: with the above command and steps I was able to run the unit test for the FooTest class in my computer.